# Trying to estimate difficulty of this idea

Tags: html, wordpress, squarespace

I have a simple question. Hard to explain it easily but is it possible to create a short quiz for the consumer to allow for a cool refining process? For example, let's say I am selling cars.

The user is prompted at the home page of the site.

Question 1: What kind of car? (SUV, Sedan, Sports, etc)

Question 2: What color? (Black, Blue, Red, etc)

Question 3: What price? (30k+, 50+k, etc)

My site would then display the cars that fit the user's answers.

Does anyone know if this is possible using Squarespace or would I have to use Wordpress and make the theme myself? I have some coding experience but by no means am I in an expert.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do isn't possible with out-of-the-box Squarespace tools, because they don't support logic or filtering in their forms (yet). However, you could use a 3rd-party tool that does, then just embed it into your site. I would recommend:

- Formkeep (https://formkeep.com)
- Typeform (https://typeform.com)
- Formstack

Each will integrate within your Squarespace site — I think they all use iFrames.